# Looping through orders of magnitude in R

Tags: r, for-loop

for(x in 0.00001:10000)
How do I structure the loop to get it to return: 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000?

Comment: for (x in 10^(-5:4))

Answer (score 0):

No loops are necessary because the exponent function is vectorized, i.e. it automatically accepts multiple values and applies the same operation to each:

```r
10^(-5:4)
```